# hrtimer signal handler in user space?

Tags: timer, kernel, signals, userspace

I've set up multiple hrtimers for a satellite I'm building as part of my research group. Ideally, I'd like the access to these timers in the user space, so I'm wondering if there's a way to have the hrtimer generate a signal that can be handled in user space. Is that possible?